# Bind Slave Server Notify after adding new zone

Tags: ubuntu, domain-name-system, bind, dns-zone

I am new to DNS Setup, i have recently setup DNS server Master and Slave using bind9. Here is my config...

Master DNS - ns1.example.com. - 192.0.2.1
Slave DNS - ns2.example.com. - 192.0.2.2

**named.conf.options**

```
options {
        directory "/var/cache/bind";
        recursion no;
        allow-transfer { none; };

        dnssec-validation auto;

        auth-nxdomain no;    # conform to RFC1035
        listen-on-v6 { any; };
};
```

**named.conf.local**

```
zone "example.com" {
    type master;
    file "/etc/bind/zones/db.example.com";
    allow-transfer { 192.0.2.2; };
};
```

**Slave named.conf.local**

```
zone "example.com" {
    type slave;
    file "db.example.com";
    masters { 192.0.2.1; };
};
```

This setup works perfect, but now i want to add another domain. So should i only update `named.conf.local` at master Sever and DNS server would be notified automatically...

For example...

```
zone "example2.com" {
    type master;
    file "/etc/bind/zones/db.example.com";
    allow-transfer { 192.0.2.2; };
};
```

I am really confused with this, please suggest next step when i add more domains zones. Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

The traditional approach is very straightforward. You described how you set up one zone properly with a master and a slave, just do the exact same thing for the next zone as well and that will work too.
Ie, add a `type master` zone on one server and a `type slave` zone on the other server.

Notify messages make it possible to get the servers with slave zones to update immediately instead of waiting for the `SOA REFRESH` timer to expire, but these are not used to add new zones.

However, starting with BIND 9.11 there's also the [Catalog Zones](http://ftp.isc.org/isc/bind9/cur/9.11/doc/arm/Bv9ARM.ch04.html#catz-info) feature, which allows setting up a zone with special semantics which defines a list of zones that should be added as slave zones as this special zone is updated with new entries.

Answer (score 0):

if your adding another domain, and you want Master/Slave, then you would need to add the master and slave zone references for new domain in both named.conf.local (below), then create the db.example1.com zone file on the master and restart both named/bind9 services. the db.example1.com file should then update the slave from the master zone file you created on the master.

named.conf.local

```
zone "example1.com" {
    type master;
    file "db.example1.com";
    allow-transfer { 192.0.2.2; };
};
```

Slave named.conf.local

```
zone "example1.com" {
    type slave;
    file "db.example1.com";
    masters { 192.0.2.1; };
};
```